# How to install packages in Azure Synapse C# notebooks?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, azure-synapse

I need to use a few packages to run notebooks in Synapse in C#. Running the following snippet, I get an error:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
```

```
(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IdentityModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
(6,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
(7,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I referred to [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/) documentation and tried to use the following code to install the package:

```
#r "nuget: Azure.Storage.Blobs, 12.10.0"
```

I get the following error:

```
Installing package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blobs, version 12.10.0...Installing package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blobs, version 12.10.0....../tmp/nuget/8572--6c519d5e-0a47-4b01-8cdb-d3d9d5a2562c/Project.fsproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blobs. No packages exist with this id in source(s): https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json, nuget.org
```

Is it possible to use these packages in Synapse Notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested in our local environment, by creating a  C# notebook in  azure synapse analytics workspace followed by creating apache spark pools.

we have successfully installed the below packages

```
#r "nuget: Azure.Storage.Blobs, 12.10.0" 
#r "nuget:Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,5.2.9"
#r "nuget:Azure.Storage.Common,12.9.0"
#r "nuget:Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets,4.3.0-beta.2"
```

Here is the reference output screen shot.

[image]

Post the installation you can use those installed package by using the keyword `using` as shown in below :

[image]

We didn't found any of the below nugget packages to install

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.Azure;
```

For storage you can also install  `Azure.Storage.Common` [nugget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Common/) which includes Azure Blobs (objects), Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure Files, and Azure Queues  libraries .

`using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;` this nugget package got deprecated a newer package is available [Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets)
Depending on what functionality of Key Vault you are using (Keys, Secrets or Certificates), please use one of the following libraries:

- Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets
- Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys
- Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates

Here is the git hub [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Analytics.Synapse.Artifacts_1.0.0-preview.11/sdk/storage) for  Azure synapse Analytics SDK libraries

Comment: Hi, I checked the Azure.Storage.Blobs package but it doesn't seem to have the client-side encryption classes. Do you know which packages I can use that are not deprecated but will allow me to do the client-side encryption decryption using the envelope technique?

Comment: Based on the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption?tabs=dotnet) , [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs?view=azure-dotnet) support client side ecryption it has a class called 
blobclient options under that class you have a property called [EncryptionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet) (Gets the Encryption Scope to be used when making requests).

Comment: Here is the reference document for [Azure storage client libraries for .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage)